# Unable to Commit to git/ Fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict

Tags: c, coursera-api

I was trying to commit on git, but it showed an error message as screenshot displayed below "error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files."
[Error shown after git commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VKjG.png)

So I checked the git status, where as it responds as following:
[git status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iNIj.png)

I've tried some solutions such as git stash as someone suggested online, but seems not working.

How can I successfully commit my file?

P.S. this is a Coursera course submission if you need more detail about the commit background, but I guess makes no differences.

Comment: I would copy the c file out of the directory, `git reset --hard && git pull` then copy it back in and try to commit. You may also need to delete the txt file again before you commit if that is an important change.

Comment: [Why images of errors are a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you executed the command `git pull` before this. 
Run the `git merge --abort` as suggested in the message `git status`, after this  you commit the changes.

Comment: I tried it but now it said                                                                                                
"CONFLICT (modify/delete) : 06_rect/grade.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in 2ca8732b0bfad6a38cdf6ae4c2a89b538873bd1. Version 2ca8732b0bfad6a38cdf6ae4c2a89b538873bd1 of 06_rect/grade.txt left in tree.                                     Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result."                                                            Does this mean I changed some root file?